# Is Mac OS X POSIX-incompliant? (timer_settime)

Tags: macos, unix, posix

I've written a program in C++ that uses the `timer_settime` function under Ubuntu, and then asked my friend to try to compile it under Mac OS X. The man page of `timer_settime` says that this function conforms to POSIX.1-2001, but under OS X (which is claimed to conform POSIX) the g++ gives compilation errors. The web search has shown that this function is absent from OS X API.

Does that mean that OS X does not conform completely to POSIX, or do I misunderstand what does the POSIX-compliance mean?

EDIT: I've looked through the [POSIX draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n4217.pdf) and found this function on page 2063 in the alphabetical list of system interfaces just next to the standard C functions such as `printf`, thus it does not seem to me that `timer_settime` is some sort of extension of the standard.

Comment: It looks to me like `timer_settime()` is part of an *optional POSIX extension*. It's perfectly possible for an OS to be POSIX-compliant but not implement that extension.

Comment: Here is the cite from "Linux system programming" by R. Love in section about `timer_settime` and related functions:

"The POSIX clocks family of timer interfaces is undoubtedly the most
advanced but also the newest (ergo the least portable) and most complicated to use. If simplicity or portability is a prime motivator, setitimer() is most likely a better choice."

Nothing said about extensions, as far as I can see, but the interface is considered "new".

Comment: 2 @Ken By the way it is somewhat weird to me that the standard that has been designed to make programs portable to all compliant systems could define optional extensions. Could you please provide a link where I can read about POSIX extensions?

Comment: I don't have anything definitive. Here's one discussion I found: http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1200444

Comment: What errors do you get? POSIX does not talk about C++. Please compile with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @FUZxxl `error: use of undeclared identifier 'timer_settime'`. The file that uses this function does include <time.h>. Since there is no declaration of this function in time.h i believe that `cc` won't compile it either.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that the advanced timer functions like `timer_settime` were indeed a part of POSIX real-time extension as Ken Thomases has suggested. Citing the change history of the documentation for this function:

> *Issue 6*
>
> The timer_getoverrun(), timer_gettime(), and timer_settime() functions are marked as part of the Timers option.
>
> *Issue 7*
>
> The timer_getoverrun(), timer_gettime(), and timer_settime() functions are moved from the Timers option to the Base.

The latest POSIX standard, POSIX.1-2008, issue 7, was released quite recently, in 2013. My friend's computer runs OS X 10.9 which was released also in the late 2013, thus I suppose it does not conform to the latest standard. However, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX.1-2008) that the latest OS X v10.10 "Yosemite", that was released in late 2014, is "fully POSIX-compliant".

After all, however, I still don't understand how one is supposed to write portable code when certain functions are silently marked as 'extensions' by standard and the man pages do not mention this significant fact.